# make an array out of JSON code nested inside two keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I want to a javascript make an array out of this JSON code

```
{

 Technical Analysis: RSI:{

 2017-07-07 16:00: {RSI: "50.2925"},

 2017-07-07 15:45: {RSI: "54.1255"},

 2017-07-07 15:30: {RSI: "55.0698"},

 2017-07-07 15:15: {RSI: "52.0587"},

 2017-07-07 15:00: {RSI: "55.4002"},

 2017-07-07 14:45: {RSI: "57.9093"}

}
}
```

I know how to do it generally, I mean it’s not rocket science, you just have to parse it and use a for in loop. But the thing is that the content I want to be inside the array, not only sits inside a key, it sits inside two keys! Therefore I don’t know how to access it. I would think that it has to be something like this:

```
parsedDoc[“Technical Analysis”]
```

or:

```
parsedDoc[“Technical Analysis: RSI”]
```

or:

```
parsedDoc[“Technical Analysis”][“RSI”]
```

But none of these seems to work, can anyone help me out here.

Comment: First of all this is not valid JSON. Correct your JSON errors and they try to parse your JSON object.

Comment: That is not JSON. The JSON spec for an object requires keys to be strings and therefore quoted.  See http://json.org/

Comment: Also note there are no arrays in any of what is shown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have invalid JSON there, correct it to be valid JSON and your last approach will work.

A smaller version of your example that is valid JSON:

```
var parsedDoc = {
  "Technical Analysis": {
    "RSI":{
      "2017-07-07 16:00": {
        "RSI": "50.2925"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

now

`parsedDoc["Technical Analysis"]["RSI"]` returns:

```
"2017-07-07 16:00": { 
  "RSI": 50.2925
}
```